# Checkbox Jquery. Всем по name

Tags: jquery

Приветствую. 
Есть несколько табов со списком юзеров.
html (кусок):

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="group_2" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="g2" class="chk-all" id="#group_2" value="Администрация: Все"> Всем
                </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="g2" value="Пользователь 1"> Пользователь 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group_3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="g3" class="chk-all" id="#group_3"
                           value="Персонал: Все"> Всем
                </li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="g3" value="Юзер 1"> Юзер 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Необходимо собирать values инпутов и выводить их на экран в строке.

```
<p class="p-send-msg">Получатели сообщения: <span class="send_msg"> </span></p>
```

Вопрос в том, как обработать "Всем"? Сейчас при нажатии на "Всем" выделяются все элементы под ним и добавляются в строку. Сняли галку со "Всем" - список очистился.
Хотелось бы, как у людей: если выбрали все элементы списка, то автоматом получили галку на "Всем". Сняли с одного - галку и текст в списке "Всем" удалять. 
Скрипт:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () { // Событие по изменению чекбокса
var txt = '', // переменная, хранящая значение input
    chks = $(document.getElementsByName(this.name)), // запоминаем имя input
    all = chks.filter('.chk-all'); // запоминаем элемент с классом chk-all

if ($(this).hasClass('chk-all')) { // если чекбокс имеет класс chk-all
    $(chks).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked')); // взять свойство этого чекбокса и поменять у всех input то же свойство на текущее свойство чекбокса chk-all
}

$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () { // цикл для каждого

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) { // если отмечен
        txt += ($(this).val() + ', '); // добавляем в переменную значение input
        $('.send_msg').text(txt); // отображаем текст на экране

    }
    else if (!txt) {
        $('.send_msg').empty(); // если переменная пустая, очищаем поле на экране
    }
    //console.log(txt, txt.length);
    });
});
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chk-all").click(function() {
    if ($(this)[0].checked) {
      $("[name=" + $(this).attr("name") + "]").prop("checked", true);

    } else {
      $("[name=" + $(this).attr("name") + "]").prop("checked", false);

    }
    foo();
  });

  $("input").click(function() {
    if (!$(this)[0].checked) {
      $(".chk-all[name=" + $(this).attr("name") + "]").prop("checked", false);
      $(this).find("input").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $(this).find("input").prop("checked", false);
    }
    foo();
  })
});

function foo() {
  var text = "";
  $("input").each(function(i, item) {
    if (!$(item).hasClass("chk-all")) {
      if ($("input")[i].checked)
        text += $(item).val() + " , ";
    }
  })
  $("#xxx").html(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="group_2" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="g2" class="chk-all" id="#group_2" value="Администрация: Все">Всем
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="g2" value="Пользователь 1">Пользователь 1</li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="g2" value="Пользователь 2">Пользователь 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="group_3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="g3" class="chk-all" id="#group_3" value="Персонал: Все">Всем
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="g3" value="Юзер 1">Юзер 1</li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" name="g3" value="Юзер 2">Юзер 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span id="xxx"></span>
```

Comment: C.Raf.T, спасибо за ответ. Не хотелось бы менять структуру разметки. У меня список заполняется из бд. Различаются списки только именами. Нужен какой-то универсальный подход, обрабатывая списки по именам инпутов. Предложенный Вами способ не совсем мне подходит.

Comment: @Coveraver не вопрос..))

Comment: C.Raf.T, это гениально!)